# Get Counts of Distinct Values into single row Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a table that is roughly as follows...

```
userid, productid, timestamp
1, 1, 2015-10-01 08:15:59
1, 2, 2015-10-01 08:16:59
2, 1, 2015-10-01 08:18:59
3, 1, 2015-10-01 08:19:59
1, 3, 2015-10-01 08:20:59
2, 1, 2015-10-01 08:21:59
```

My desired output is as follows...

```
user, product1Count, product2Count, product3Count
1, 1, 1, 1
2, 2, 0, 0
3, 1, 0, 0
```

I have gotten the following so far. But I am not sure how to take this table and flatten it into a single row for each user.

Query:

```
Select user_id, product_id, count(*) 
from masampleinput
group by user_id, product_id
```

Output:

```
User, product, count
1, 1, 1
1, 2, 1
1, 3, 1
2, 1, 2
3, 1, 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope the below query helps you:

```
select userid,
MAX(CASE WHEN productid = 1 THEN count ELSE null END) as product1count,
MAX(CASE WHEN productid = 2 THEN count ELSE null END) as product2count,
MAX(CASE WHEN productid = 3 THEN count ELSE null END) as product3count
from 
(Select user_id, product_id, count(*) 
from masampleinput
group by user_id, product_id)
GROUP BY userid
```

Comment: You probably meant to put `0` instead of `null` in your `CASE` statements.

Comment: I have 50 products, this does not seem like a great way for that many... I have also 4 different time ranges I want to join...